Blender Addon Question - Change World Color
Is there a way to add an option to change the World Surface Color and Strength settings via a button?
I already coded out the panel and everything, but maybe it's just based on the specific context, which I currently have: world = context.world Which removes everything from my label that I created. This is confusing me, maybe there is already a question similar out there or here and I haven't found it. I apologize for the repeated question, if that's the case.
Thank you.
import bpy

class Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Panel"
    bl_idname = "PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Panel'

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    
    #world = context.world

    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="Select a shader")
    row.operator()


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Panel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


can you add more details as its not so clear what you mean by add an option to change the world surface color

The current world is not available directly with the context, but the current scene. Use context.scene.world

The current world is not available directly with the context, but the current scene. Use context.scene.world :
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout        
        world = context.scene.world
        node = world.node_tree.nodes["Background"]
        layout.prop(node.inputs["Color"], "default_value", text="Color")
        layout.prop(node.inputs["Strength"], "default_value", text="Strength")


